# NumPy Array Indexing and Replacing

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a 3d numpy array as follows:

```
(3L, 5L, 5L)
```

If one element in 3d positions, for instance, `[150, 160, 170]` exists. How can I convert all of them into `[0,0,0]`?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,5,5))
a[0,2:4,2:4] = 150
a[0,0:1,0:1] = 150 #important!
a[1,2:4,2:4] = 160
a[2,2:4,2:4] = 170
print a
```

The expected result should be:

```
[[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]

 [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]]
```

Comment: np.where( condition )

Comment: The question and example should make it clearer that the `[150,160,170]` have to occur together.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes! They should be together!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would convert into a stack of triples:

```
b = np.reshape(a.transpose(2, 1, 0), [25,3])
```

Then find the values you want:

```
idx = np.where((b == np.array([150, 160, 170])).all(axis=1))
```

And replace with whatever value you want:

```
b[idx] = 0
```

And finally convert back to the original shape:

```
c = np.reshape(b, [5, 5, 3]).transpose(2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Construct your `a`:

```
In [48]: a=np.ones((3,5,5))    
In [49]: a[0,2:4,2:4]=150
In [50]: a[1,2:4,2:4]=160
In [51]: a[2,2:4,2:4]=170

In [52]: a
Out[52]: 
array([[[   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  150.,  150.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  150.,  150.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.]],

       [[   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  160.,  160.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  160.,  160.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.]],

       [[   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  170.,  170.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,  170.,  170.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.]]])
```

Boolean of all places where the values, on the 1st dimension, are `[150,160,170]`.  The key is to expand this to a 3d, shape `(3,1,1)` that can be broadcast to `(3,5,5)` and compared with `a`:

```
In [53]: I = a==np.array([150,160,170])[:,None,None]

In [54]: I
Out[54]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

Now it's trivial to change all those slots with value `True` to `0`:

```
In [55]: a[I]=0

In [56]: a
Out[56]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

Looking at the comments on a deleted answer I see you really want a case where all 3 values match.  That is, contrary to your example, there may be other slots `a[0,...]` is 150, etc. that you don't want to change.

You could still work with this `I`, by just taking an `all` on the 1st axis:

```
In [58]: a[:,I.all(axis=0)]=2

In [59]: a
Out[59]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

Conceptually my answer is not that different from the accepted one.  That reshapes the array into a 2d, so the matching can be done with a 1d `[150,160,170]`.  Actually it is automatically reshaped to `(1,3)` which can be broadcast agains `(25,3)` array.  Transposing and reshaping is a convenient way to standardize the format of problems like this, though it often isn't necessary.

---

It may help to split that last action up:

```
In [60]: J=I.all(axis=0)

In [61]: J
Out[61]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [62]: a[:, J] = 3
```

or use `np.where` to convert the boolean array to 2 list of indices:

```
In [73]: jj=np.where(J)
In [74]: jj
Out[74]: (array([2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 2, 3], dtype=int32))

In [75]: a[:, jj[0], jj[1]] = 4
```

`a[:,jj]` doesn't work, but `a[(slice(None),)+jj]` does.  This last expression constructs a 3 element tuple, the equivalent to [75]'s.

I could also expand `J` to a size and shape that matches `a`:

```
In [90]: K=J[None,...].repeat(3,0)
In [91]: K
Out[91]: 
array([[[False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False],
        ....]], dtype=bool)
```

and use `a[K]`.

Comment: Following `a[:,I.all(axis=0)]=2` part is little difficult. Can not the indices be pre-obtained using `I = a==np.array([150,160,170])[:,None,None]` and defining some axis like (1,3)?

Comment: I've elaborated on the `I.all` indexing.